# Remap goto line in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to remap goto line in android studio. But I can honestly not find it in the keymap settings. Does anyone one know what the name of goto line is in android studio so I can remap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Menu | Navigate | Line...